# More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/groovy-release-info.properties'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, exception

If i try to build my app, i'll receive this error:

> DuplicateRelativeFileException: More than one file was found with OS independent path 'META-INF/groovy-release-info.properties

and this:

> Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.example"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
   }
}

dependencies {
   implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
   implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
   implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
   implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.13.0'
   implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
   implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
   implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
   implementation 'io.rest-assured:json-path:3.3.0'
   testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
   testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
   testImplementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.13.0'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
   androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
   core:3.0.2'
}
```

I try to solve this problem with adding the following peace of code to my gradle.build file:

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/groovy-release-info.properties'
}
```

But then i'll get this error:

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process C:\Users\[myUserNamePlaceholder]\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.codehaus.groovy\groovy\2.4.15\74b7e0b99526c569e3a59cb84dbcc6204d601ee6\groovy-2.4.15.jar
```

Could you help me please. I've been trying to solve this problem for hours. I appreciate any answer that helps me a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. The problem occurred when I inserted the following dependencies into my gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.8.5'
```

After long research I have found a solution. I had to add compile options to my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    ...
}
```

and to my gradle.properties

```
android.enableD8=true
```

After that it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try using pickFirst to select just only one of the file:

```
packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'META-INF/groovy-release-info.properties'
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't solve my problem. Additionally I get the following exception `com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Error: MethodHandle.invoke and MethodHandle.invokeExact are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)`